# Is there a way to import modules from a Haskell package build without installing it?

Tags: haskell, import, build, cabal

Is there a way to import (using either `import` or `m +`) a module from a Haskell package that has been built locally, but not installed (e.g., with Cabal)?

For example, if I built a package in a local directory, so that, say, `MyPkg/dist/build/` contains all of the same `.dyn_hi`, `.hi`, `.a`, and `.dylib` files and subfolders that a Cabal-installed version would have in (for example) `MyPkg-0.0.1.0`, is there a way to import a module from that with

```
import MyPkg.Sub
```

or

```
:m + MyPkg.Sub
```

as I would if it had been installed?

I've tried `cd`ing (both before and within GHCi) to `MyPkg/dist/build/` (and every place along the way) and have also tried `ghci -i...` and `:set -i...` to the same locations. But in all cases the only way I can get `import` or `:m +` to work, is by installing the package.

I understand how to install, as well as how to install using a sandbox. But is there a way to import (given that the files are "right there") without installing?

---

I know that the answer to this must be (perhaps a qualified) "yes", because my IDE accomplishes this somehow: Within the same project, I can include applications that use `import` successfully, without having to install the package from which the modules are imported.

Comment: You *could* copy-and-paste, and then comment in the necessary links and such. I imagine that your IDE looks at hackage, and then just reads the necessary type signatures and so on.

Comment: With [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) you can keep a package install local and load it by running `stack ghci` in your project directory. I realize this is not really an answer to your question but maybe it can still be of use.

Comment: It's pretty easy to make a temporary package database, install to that database, and point ghci at that package database. In fact, this is such a common wish, that the steps are rolled up into the `cabal repl` command; or you can run just the ghci step with `cabal exec ghci` (which will not rebuild your package when it's dirty, using whatever existing build has been done).

Comment: Soon, soon, this should all get easier. "No-reinstall cabal" is in public beta; it brings Nix ideas to the package database, so making a new sandbox won't generally need a "get a cup of coffee" step.